TV episode with strange music box device
I'm trying to identify an unknown fantasy film or episode from a TV series - I'm not sure which.
The scene involves a trickster like character who causes chaos with a pocket sized wind up device similar to a music box. The device is made of mostly wood and brass with hand crank on one end and a tiny phonograph horn on the other. When it's cranked, a bunch of gears turn which operate small valves on a flute like tube. No sound comes out but the device causes a chain of unlikely events to occur.
I believe the show was from the 90's or early 2000's.

Mystery solved. The scene that was stuck in my head is from a fantasy film called 'Ink' (2009).
The music box itself is a little larger than I thought and made of wood and copper instead of brass but otherwise my memory of the scene was very close. The box is used by Jacob the 'pathfinder' character to cause an auto accident which delivers the absent father to the same hospital as his daughter who is in a coma. Jacob is blind and has black electrical tape X's over his eyes but he can 'hear the beat' of the world...and often counts it out loud just to be annoying. The whole causality chain he creates is one of the most powerful scenes in the film and plays out like a music video with him conducting the action to the beat as if it were an orchestra.

Glad you found it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons on the left side of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.
